# Dialog when leaving entire React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-router, onbeforeunload

I'm looking for a way to show a custom confirmation dialog when user leaves the entire React application (like going to www.google.com).

There's plenty of ways to detect page changes/navigation within the app (working with react-router, Prompt, etc...) but these do not include navigating from the entire app.

There is also built-in javascript functions like `beforeunload` but you cannot customize that dialog at all (at **best** you might be able to customize the message on some browsers).

Is there any way to do this?!

Comment: sorry, `onbeforeunload` is your only option

Comment: wouldn't `componentWillUnmount` on the root component of your application solve this for you?

Comment: @sudavid4 No, `componentWillUnmount` on the root component (or the currently viewed component) is not called when navigating to an entirely different website like Google